# Trying to create a Custom Mixin for Class Based Views

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a custom mixin for my Carousel but I am getting this error  File "/src/content/urls.py", line 3, in 
from . import views
File "/src/content/views.py", line 34, in 
class IndexView(CarouselObjectMixin, ListView):
NameError: name 'CarouselObjectMixin' is not defined
the mixin that I made was added to my content app

```
class IndexView(CarouselObjectMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'index.html'
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    ordering = ['-post_date']
    ordering = ['-id']

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context
```

but the custom mixin is in my slideshow app.

Function Based View

views.py

```
def SlideShowView(request):
    carousel = Carousel.objects.all()
    context  = {
        'carousel' : carousel,
    }
    return render(request, "showcase.html", context)
```

Converted to Class Based View

views.py

```
class SlideShowView(ListView):
    model = Carousel
    context_object_name = 'carousel'
    template_name = 'showcase.html'
```

Custom Mixin

views.py

```
class CarouselObjectMixin(object):
    model = Carousel
    context_object_name = 'carousel'
    template_name = 'showcase.html'
```

Comment: Is `CarouselObjectMixin` in this file `src/content/views.py` too?

Comment: No CarouselObjectMixin is not in src/content/views.py it is located in src/slideshow/views.py

Comment: ok, I've added an answer based on, make sure to select it as accepted answer to mark this as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I got the error to go away by adding slideshow.views import CarouselObjectMixin into src/content/views.py. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it seem like `CarouselObjectMixin` is not imported in `src/content/views.py` file